# Silverlight 4 out of browser application not opening

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have developed a silverlight 4 application and set it up to run out of browser. As is always this case it loads and runs fine from my machine and my testing environments. I can install it on my clients machine but it will not load once I try and launch it, basically nothing happens. Any advice on how to proceed or test this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with the Event Viewer. Does the Silverlight stand alone encapsulate the .net framework, or do you need to ensure that your client has the most recent .net framework?

Comment: That is a good question I made the fatal error of assuming. I assumed that if it needed it to run the OOB installer would have installed it. I will have to check.